# How do I find elements of Counter list of Python over some specific frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter, pickle

I am trying to find all the elements with more than some frequency in a counter list. But I couldn't find any solution.

a=['a','a','a','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','d','d','e']

b=Counter(a)

b Counter({'a': 10, 'c': 8, 'b': 7, 'd': 2, 'e': 1})

now I want element which have frequency more than 2.

Comment: If we don't know what you've tried, we can't see where you went wrong.  Show us some code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could provide us with your attempt at the problem you've described, it would give us some more context about what you hope to do. You can find some tips about how to structure your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JordanSinger Please help

Comment: @AliAbbas Your code, as written, is not valid Python syntax. Can you provide us with a working version of your code, that includes only the lines relevant to your question? Thanks!

Comment: @JordanSinger Sorry for that Now may be you get what I am trying to expalin

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry for that Now may be you get some idea what I am trying to ask.

Comment: @AliAbbas Thank you! Please see blhsing's answer below, as I believe it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Counter dict `{'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 4, 'd': 2, 'e': 1}` as variable `db` you can use dict comprehension to generate a dict of items with frequency greater than 2 with:

```
{k: c for k, c in db.items() if c > 2}
```

Comment: I am a bigner in python, I know PHP well, I have no idea how this perticular code is working. It's working absalutely fine. But I want to know its working. Can you help me in this?

Comment: List/dict/set comprehension is a construct unique to Python. Please read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me.